# Var emptied from child view to parent view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got a really strange behavior in my views. I have a parent view called "access.blade.php" and child view "survey.blade.php".

I instanciated 2 vars in the parent view which are empty arrays.

I populate them in the child view but when i var_dump them in the parent view after the include of the child view, my var are empty...

here is the parent view :

```
@extends('template')

@section('title')
    Compile result
@stop

@section('content')

<div id="access" class="container-fluid main-content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-push-3 col-xs-push-3">

            <div class="page-title white-text text-center">
                <h1>Access Report</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container fluid-height clearfix">

                <?php
                    $session = Sessions::find($params['session_id']);
                    $userNotSeen = [];
                    $userSeen = [];
                ?>

                <div class="heading">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-xl pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#complianceModal">Compliance</button>
                    Access Report for
                    {{ isset($result->content->display_name) ? $result->content->display_name : $result->content->title }}


                    <p>
                        Journey: {{ $session->location_id != null ? $session->location->city : $session->place }}
                    </p>

                </div>

                <div class="row text-center"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        @if($result != null)
                            @if($result->content_type == 1)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.tasklist')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 2)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.resources')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 3)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.survey')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 4)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.feedback')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 5)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.memo')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 6)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.gear')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 7)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.sinsim')
                            @elseif($result->content_type == 8)
                                @include('contents.partials.access.changr')
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <p class="text-center">{{ $errors }}</p>
                        @endif

                        <pre>
                            {{ var_dump($userNotSeen) }}
                        </pre>
                         <pre>
                            {{ var_dump($userSeen) }}
                        </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    @include('contents.partials.modal')
@stop
```

And here is my child view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Viewed</th>
        <th class="text-center">Submitted</th>
        <th class="text-center">Personnal Results</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if(isset($result->data))
        @forelse($result->data as $key => $value)
            <tr {{ $value->view == 0 ? 'class="notyetseen"' : ''; }}>
                <td>{{ $value->fullname }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $value->view == 0 ? 'No' : 'Yes' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $value->done == 0 ? 'No' : 'Yes' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a href="/manage/{{ $params['session_id'] }}/content/{{ $params['content_id'] }}/{{ $params['content_type'] }}/access/{{ $key }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Get results</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                if($value->view == 0) {
                    array_push($userNotSeen, $key);
                } else {
                    array_push($userSeen, $key);
                }
            ?>
        @empty
            <tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">{{ $errors }}</td></tr>
        @endforelse
    @else
        <tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">No participants for this journey</td></tr>
    @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have an idea about the why it doesn't work: maybe the parent view is loaded completly before the child view, so my var are not yet populated.

If it is the case, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never EVER include logic in your templates. Move this logic to your controller and pass results to a view. Templates are only for displaying your data.

> If you have to use `<?php` in your **Blade** template, you are doing something wrong.

Second, Blade compiles your templates separately. It is not a simple `include(__child_template__)`. That's why while compiling each of your templates, Blade works with completely different variable scopes and `$userNotSeen` in *access.blade.php* template is not the same as in your *survey.blade.php*.